# What is the minimum system requirement to launch Pentaho server?

Tags: pentaho

My computer is Windows7 64bit , RAM : 4Gb , Processor : Core2 Duo 2.26 GHz. When I launch the start-pentaho batch file ( biserver-ce-6.1.0.1-196 ) then the console exits after a while when the system is initialized. So I wondered my computer lacks some requirements. So what is the minimum system requirements to launch the server ?

Comment: The reason behind console getting close is you have not define JAVA_HOME path in your environment variable.

Comment: it is already set.

Comment: There's no way to help with the information provided.

Answer (score 0):

> The Pentaho server is hardware-independent and runs on server-class computers that comply with these specifications for minimum hardware and required operating systems:
>
> Hardware -64 bit
>   Processor: Intel EM64T or AMD64 Dual-Core
>
> RAM: 8 GB with 4 GB dedicated to Pentaho servers
>
> Disk Space: 20 GB free after installation
>
> Operating System—64 bit
>
> Microsoft Windows 2008 Server R2 & 2012 Server R2
>
> CentOS 6 & 7
>
> Red Hat Enterprise 6 & 7
>
> Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS & 16.04 LTS
>
> SUSE Linux SLES 11 (SP3+)
>
> Workstation
>
> These Pentaho design tools are hardware-independent and run on client-class computers that comply with these specifications for minimum hardware and required operation systems.
>
> Pentaho Aggregation Designer
>
> Pentaho Data Integration
>
> Pentaho Metadata Editor
>
> Pentaho Report Designer
>
> Pentaho Schema Workbench
>
> Hardware
>   Processors:Apple Macintosh Dual-Core Intel EM64T or AMD64 Dual-Core
>
> RAM: 2 GB RAM for most of the design tools, PDI requires 2 GB dedicated
>
> Disk Space: 2 GB free after installation
>
> Minimum Screen Size: 1280 x 960
>
> Software
>
> Microsoft Windows 7, 8, & 10
>
> Ubuntu Desktop 14.04 LTS & 16.04
>
> OS X 10.11 & 10.12

From: https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/7.1/0D0/160/000